# Trying to use gRPC in Python with multiple servers or possibly multiplexing

Tags: python, server, client, grpc, multiplexing

Our use case involves one class that has to remotely initialize several instances of another class (each on a different IoT device) and has to get certain results from each of these instances. At most, we would need to receive 30 messages a second from each remote client, with each message being relatively small.  What type of architecture would you all recommend to solve this?

We were thinking that each class that is located on the IoT device will serve as a server and the class that receives the results would be the client, so should we create a server, each with its own channel, for each IoT device? Or is it possible to have each IoT device use the same service on the same server (meaning there would be multiple instances of the same service on the same server but on different devices)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question would benefit from additional detail to help guide an answer.

gRPC (and its use of HTTP/2) are 'heavier' protocols than e.g. MQTT. MQTT is more commonly used with IoT devices as it has a smaller footprint. REST/HTTP (even though heavier than MQTT) may also have benefits for you over gRPC/HTTP2.

If you're committed to gRPC, I wonder whether it would not be better to invert your proposed architecture and have the IoT device be the client? This seems to provide additional security in that the clients initiate communications with your servers rather than expose services. Either way (and if you decide to use MQTT), hopefully you'll be using mTLS. I assume (!?) client implementations are smaller than server implementations.

Regardless of the orientation, clients and servers can (independently) stream messages. The IoT devices (client or server) could stream the 30 messages/second. The servers could stream management|control messages.

I've no experience managing fleets of IoT devices but, remote management|monitoring and over-the-air upgrades|patching are, I assume, important requirements for you. gRPC does not limit any of these capabilities **but** debugging can be more challenging. With e.g. REST/HTTP, it is trivial to curl endpoints but with gRPC (even with the excellent [`grpcurl`](https://github.com/fullstorydev/grpcurl)) you'll be constrained to the services implemented. Yes, you can't call a non-existent REST API either but I find remote-debugging gRPC services more challenging than REST.

Comment: So, for python, would you recommend using something like the paho library that is built for MQTT or even RabbitMQ since it has a much more robust message queueing architecture? Also, if it isn't too much of a hassle, could you link a resource or two about how to do remote management with MQTT or REST/HTTP with python?

Comment: I recommend you evaluate these technologies for your own needs. Eclipse's Paho MQTT libraries are commonly used and good. RabbitMQ is not MQTT. MQTT is commonly-used w/ IoT because it's lightweight (while providing security). My point wrt remote management is that, a binary-oriented protocol like gRPC can make interacting with devices more challenging than a text-based protocol like REST/HTTP.

Comment: Thank you for the help!